# How to make the pop-up box in the bottom left of the 3D viewport appear immediately when activating a Transform tool?

Tags: transforms

So many times I want to use the options in the bot left panel (Operator panel) when using a transform tool
but it doesnt pop up unless I use the tool even tho i have it selected....

This is a problem because I want for example for Inset tool to check Individual faces
but I cant unless I go and do it first....
Also cant use the transform and then Ctrl Z because the moment I undo it also goes away

This is just one of many examples, but how can I get the box to pop up when I enter the tool rather than just when i use it?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. The box is called the Operator Adjustment panel, aka the tweak-that-operation panel.

The fact that you want to do this makes me think you need to know that the tools themselves can be accessed without the gizmos, and will act on all selected faces generally.

Edit: gizmos are pretty much anything that shows in the 3D view that is not an object, particularly as a control.